# Add checkbox to WooCommerce checkout page based on custom "woocommerce_variation_option"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I've added an additional variation option to my products with the following code:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_variation_options', 'he_add_to_variation_option', 10, 3);
function he_add_to_variation_option( $loop, $variation_data, $variation){
    $is_trial = (get_post_meta($variation->ID, '_trialversion', true)) ? ' checked' : '';
    ?>
    <label class="tips" data-tip="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Enable this option to make as a trial version', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Trial Version?', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox variable_is_trial_version" name="_trialversion[<?php echo esc_attr( $variation->ID ); ?>]"<?php echo $is_trial;?>/>
    </label>
<?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_trialversion_option_fields'  );
function save_trialversion_option_fields( $post_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['_trialversion'] ) ){
        foreach ( $_POST['_trialversion'] as $productid=>$checked ){
            update_post_meta( $productid, '_trialversion', 'yes' );
        }
    }    
}
```

This works great, it's displayed within the variants and it's saved correctly in the database.

So far, so good.

Now, I would like to add an additional checkbox at checkout, if a product is flagged as "trial version". I'm using the "Germanized" plugin as well, which has options for custom checkboxes, but I can't get it to recognize the changes I've made with the above code.

How would I accomplish the custom checkbox for my trial version variants? With or without Germanized, at this point I just want to get it to work. Maybe there's a free plugin, but if I can just do it by adding some code, that would probably be easier.

The checkbox would have to be a required one to complete the purchase of the trial version.

Hopefully someone has an idea on how to do this. Looking forward to your replies!

Comment: Is it correct that the above works in the first instance, but if you turn off a checkbox afterwards, it remains 'on'?

Comment: No, that feature works fine. Maybe I haven't worded my issue correctly. The code above works. But what I need now is a required checkbox with text (similar to accepting to terms and services) during the checkout process to be displayed, when a product variant has the "trialversion" enabled.

Comment: if I run your code above, turn on the checkbox, save it and then turn it off, save again... it will stay on

Comment: Looks like you're right, my apologies. While this isn't the issue I'm looking to fix, it's another problem to add to the list. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a product variant has the "trialversion" enabled, a new checkbox will be added at the checkout page

> `woocommerce_save_product_variation` should not contain a foreach loop, the 2nd parameter of the function already contains a counter `$i`
>
> Normally the problem with the checkboxes should also be solved

```php
function add_to_variation_option( $loop, $variation_data, $variation){
    $is_trial = get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_trialversion', true);

    if ( $is_trial == 'yes' ) {
        $is_trial = 'checked';
    } else {
        $is_trial = '';     
    }

    ?>
    <label class="tips" data-tip="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Enable this option to make as a trial version', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
        <?php esc_html_e( 'Trial Version?', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox variable_is_trial_version" name="_trialversion[<?php echo esc_attr( $loop ); ?>]"<?php echo $is_trial;?>/>
    </label>
    <?php
}
add_action('woocommerce_variation_options', 'add_to_variation_option', 10, 3);

function save_trialversion_option_fields( $variation_id, $i ) {
    if ( !empty($_POST['_trialversion']) && !empty( $_POST['_trialversion'][$i] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_trialversion', 'yes' );
    } else {
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_trialversion', 'no' ); 
    }       
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_trialversion_option_fields', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Add checkbox field to the checkout
 **/ 
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
    // Get $product object from Cart object
    $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

    foreach( $cart as $cart_item ) {                
        // The WC_Product object
        $product = wc_get_product( $cart_item['product_id'] );

        // Checks the product type, 'variable', returns boolean
        if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            // Get variation id
            $variation_id = $cart_item['data']->get_id();

            // Get post meta
            $trialversion = get_post_meta( $variation_id, '_trialversion', true);

            // Found
            if ( $trialversion == 'yes' ) {
                $trialversion = 'found';

                // Break loop
                break;
            }
        }       
    }

    // Found
    if ( isset($trialversion) && $trialversion == 'found' ) {
        echo '<div id="my-new-field">';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'my_checkbox', array(
            'type'          => 'checkbox',
            'class'         => array('input-checkbox'),
            'label'         => __('I agree'),
            'required'  => true,
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_checkbox' ));

        echo '</div>';
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field', 10, 1 );
```